# Need help to review PostgreSQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have following SQL query which I want to use with Postgres

```
declare 
    _sql varchar varying(50);
    _whereClause varchar varying(50);
_whereClause:='and 1=1'

execute 'SELECT count(*) FROM test t WHERE 1=1' || _whereClause
```

when i'm trying to execute above query it gives error at varchar in second line.
and even some time for simple command like below

```
declare _sql varchar varying(50);
```

It gives error, but I don't know what's wrong with the code.
I have even tried to figure it out with Postgres SQL offcial site and when I tried to copy and run example given over there it's not executing.

I'm new with Postgres and I'm feeling unlucky with the Postgres SQL syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is incorrect, you should use either `VARCHAR(50)` or `CHARACTER VARYING(50)`, not `VARCHAR VARYING(50)`.
Eg.

```
DECLARE
    _sql VARCHAR(50);
    _whereClause VARCHAR(50);
```